# Query to select similar post like current

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `posts` with following rows:

```
post_id
post_title
post_image
post_body
category
```

Second table `category` where categories are stored

```
cat_id
cat_name
```

When I click on post 1 it is open in new page `post.php?post_id=1`.. What I trying to do now is on the new page to have similar post only from the same category.
This is the code that I have on single post page

```
function truncate–s($text, $chars = 80) {
    $text = $text." ";
    $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
    $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
    $text = $text." ...";
    return $text;
}
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['post_id'])){
                $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $post_id");
            foreach ($query as $row) {

                    echo '<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="portfolio-slider-wrapper">
                                <ul id="portfolio-slider">
                                <h4>'.$row['post_title'].'</h4>
                                <hr>
                                    <li><img src="'.$row['post_image'].'" alt="" class="img-responsive"/> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <div class="blog-desc">

                            <ul class="post-meta-links list-inline">
                                <li><a href="#"><span> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>'.$row['post_date'].'</a></li>                                    
                            </ul>
                    <p>
                        '.$row['post_body'].'
                    </p>
            </div>
  }
  echo ' <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="related-post">
        <h4>Related</h4>
        <hr>';
         $query1 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON posts.category=category.cat_id LIMIT 3");             
        foreach ($query1 as $post) {                  

         echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                 <div class="rel-post">

                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="'.$post['post_image'].'" alt="" lass="img-responsive">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4>'.$post['post_title'].'</h4>
                           <p>'.truncate–s($post['post_body']).'</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                 </div>
                </div>';
            }
```

Currently when I open some post it doesn't mater what ID have it's always load first 3 post from the database table.

How to load the posts from same category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with that query.

`"SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON posts.category=category.cat_id WHERE posts.category = '".$row['category']."' LIMIT 3"`

Be sure that you have only one element in $query.

Comment: Just is there an option to exclude the current post from the result of that query because currently it is shown also in the result?

Comment: `WHERE posts.category = '".$row['category']."' AND posts.post_id != '".$row['post_id']."'` use this query :)